# Problems Formatting .CSV Output

Tags: java, export-to-csv

I am currently programming an assignment for a class of mine. I am trying to print to my output file to a csv file. The problem is, after I end my second print statement, my output doesn't line up after starting the print statement in my while loop.

For example, here is my code:

```
oFile = new PrintStream(new File("output.csv"));
        oFile.println("First Name" + "," + "Last Name" + "," + "Lecture Section"+","+"Lab Section"+","+"Lab 1"+","+"Lab 2"+","+"Lab 3"+","+"Lab 4"+","+"Lab 5"+","+"Lab 6"+","+"Lab 7"+","+"Lab 8"+","+"Lab 9"+","+"Lab 10");

        loadLectureArray();
        loadLabArray();
        sortClassSections();

        for (int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i++) {
            oFile.println(stud.get(i).getStudFirstName() + ","+stud.get(i).getStudLastName()+","+stud.get(i).getStudLectureNum()+","+stud.get(i).getStudLabNum()+",");

            while (numLab < 10 && i < stud.size()) {
                oFile.println(labStud.get(i).grades.getStudLabGrade()[numLab]);
                numLab++;
            }
            numLab = 0;
        }
```

After I execute my while loop, my new data is printed in-between my header and other data.  Some of the code is not perfect, but currently I am just seeking advice about reformatting my output to line back up with the print statements.

This is my first time exporting a file to csv, so if there is something I am doing wrong or need to change, please let me know! I hope you can make sense out of what I'm trying to ask for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to read/write CSV files, I strongly recommend using a CSV library, to ensure correct encoding of text values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, println always prints a newline, so you get a newline after every grade. you should be able to get what you want using `oFile.print(...)` instead of `oFile.println(...)` inside the for loop and just one `oFile.println()` at the very end of it.

i also noticed that the test for `i < stud.size()` in the head of the while loop is redundant since nothing should be changing either i or stud.size() between this test and the same test in the head of the for loop.